# Understanding different approaches for layer widths

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to figure out what would be the fundamental difference between these 3 types of layer widths assuming the same input size/output size and only changing the width of the layers and not the layer types or amount of layers.

Does anyone have some resources on this topic or past experience with this?

[image]